# crawl a website for data at frequent intervals

Tags: perl

I need to crawl a website and retrieve certain data that keeps getting updated every few minutes. How do i do this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `sleep` to control wait period, and use [`WWW::Mechanize`](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.64/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) for data retrieval:

```
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
my $url = "http://www.nytimes.com";  # a sample webpage
while (1) {
    $mech->get($url);
    print $mech->content(format => 'text');  # read docs for WWW::Mechanize for advanced content processing
    sleep 300;  # wait for 5 minutes
}
```

EDIT: improved the sample content retrieval process.

Comment: Be a good Web citizen and make that [GET request conditional](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3). If the page has not changed, it does not need to be downloaded again.

Comment: Downvote: direct access to the innards of the object is not any good. Use the [`decoded_content` method inherited from `HTTP::Message`](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Message#%24mess-%3Edecoded_content%28_%25options_%29) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Load [`WWW::Mechanize`](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize) for crawling, use the [`mirror` method inherited from `LWP::UserAgent`](http://p3rl.org/LWP::UserAgent#%24ua-%3Emirror%28_%24url%2C_%24filename_%29).